# Rotate Image using RotateFlip in C#

Tags: c#

I have this code to rotate an image in an if loop in C# Windows Form application, but the Form does not show anything in the form output.

Can anyone help?

```
this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(PictureBox1);
PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
PictureBox1.Image = bitmap; //Image.FromFile(@"C:\image.jpg");
PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
PictureBox1.Image = (Image)(RotateImg(bitmap, 30.0f, Color.Transparent));
```

Comment: What is the code you are using for RotateImg, and how are you using above code in your If statement.

Answer (score 6):

if you need to rotate an image on common angles you can use RotateFlip method with ease.
Please see my sample code:

```
string fileName = "somefile.png";
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat imageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;
Bitmap bitmap =(Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(fileName );
//this will rotate image to the left...
bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
//lets save result back to file...
bitmap.Save(fileName, imageFormat);
bitmap.Dispose();
```

That's all, hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
PictureBox1.Images.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
PictureBox1.Refresh();
```