# How to rotate an image in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, image-manipulation

I am creating a photo app and I need to rotate my taken images by 90 degrees. I don't need to *display* them rotated, I actually need them to be *saved* that way so XAML transforms are not an option for me. I am aware that Nokia Imaging SDK is capable of that, but I am not using the SDK and it would be a bit overkill to use the whole SDK just to rotate an image by 90 degrees. I've found this: [rotate image using rotateflip in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924711/rotate-image-using-rotateflip-in-c-sharp) but there is no `Bitmap` class in Windows Phone, that answer applies for regular Windows.

How can I rotate my image by 90 degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found the WriteableBitmapExtensions for Windows Phone (http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/). I didn't know such a library existed. It solved my problem, at least, it's much more lightweight than Nokia Imaging SDK.